# Help with finding the problem in compilation

Tags: compiling, overleaf, arxiv

I have been stuck with this for hours now. The issue is that I completed writing a paper using overleaf online compiler. It compiles with one error but generates the pdf as expected. The error message is shown below:

```
 The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used.
Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a
package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using
\usepackage{...}.
 Learn more
l.640 ...lle, A.~Beygelzimer, F.~d\textquotesingle                                                  
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Now, when I tried to submit the paper to arXiv, it simply does not compile over there and no pdf is generated. The error message is:

```
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg)
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.79
?
>! Emergency stop.
<inserted text>
$
l.79
>! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on template.log.
[verbose]: pdflatex 'template.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'template.out' (1613676344 >= 1613676343)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'template.aux' (1613676344 >= 1613676343)
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3608959/ && tex 'template.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex)
(./template.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
{article}

> ?! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
{article}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on template.log.
[verbose]: tex 'template.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'template.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***
```

Is it possible to get some clues on the error based on these messages? The document is pretty long around 12000 words, so I find it difficult to go through the entire document word by word. Any help is appreciated,

Thanks in advance! Kindly let me know if I should post any other information that might be useful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: It looks like you're running `pdftex`, not `pdflatex`.

Comment: the first error is `\textquotesingle` is not defined, you can probably find a package that defines it but I guess `\newcommand\textquotesingle{'}` would work. The other system you are using tex instead of latex.

Comment: Do you have by any chance some magic comments before `\documentclass`? The arXiv compiler doesn't like those...

Comment: `\newcommand\textquotesingle{'}` worked for me! thanks a lot!